# Selenium won't find element on page after page has reloaded

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Iv'e been having this issue were after I reload a page in java's selenium web driver, the element I declared beforehand won't be selected again to send keys. For example, I wrote this to try and figure out what my problem was.

```
package test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class googleTest {
public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

            search.sendKeys("test");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            search.sendKeys("test");
}

}
```

The first time it will select the search bar, and type in test. Afterwards, on reload, it won't send test to the search bar. I've tried re-finding it as a different WebElement, but that wont work either. I'm also using `thread.sleep` to try and figure out whats wrong, i know its not entirely suggested. I'm also using this in a more practical way, but ive made this code just for testing purposes.

I'm new to this and any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Search element again after refresh. Use implicit or better explicit waits not sleeps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after refreshing of the page the earlier pointed webElements will be cleared and gets StaleElementException.

If don't want to use the PageFactory then its better to use Implicit or Explicit waits(check visibility of element) instead of thread.sleep

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal Selenium behaviour!

When a page reloads, either you forcing it or the browser refreshes, all `WebElements` that were found on that page will now throw `StaleElementException`.

When a page reloads, you need to refresh all your elements, effectively locate them again. For this reason, most people move to [PageObject](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) model (also worth looking at [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)) ASAP, as that simplifies refreshing all your elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with it is to Identify that element again before using, as follows:

```
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

            search.sendKeys("test");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));   //Searching for it again
            search.sendKeys("test");
```

**Explanation:**

Once you refresh the page the DOM of the webPage changes and hence the element that you had identified & Stored as webelement won't be available, so You have to search for it again on the DOM after refresh.